# Problems using pip, (Exception [...] findall() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, pip

I couldn't find anything resembling this problem.

Whenever I try using pip I get this exception (using Scrapy as an example):

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\pip-script.py run on 01/16/14 16:26:32
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Scrapy in c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.20.2-py2.7.egg
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Twisted>=10.0.0 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from Scrapy)
Downloading/unpacking w3lib>=1.2 (from Scrapy)
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/w3lib/
  URLs to search for versions for w3lib>=1.2 (from Scrapy):
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/w3lib/
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/w3lib/
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir c:\users\tobias\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_Tobias...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 270, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1157, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 264, in find_requirement
    page_versions.extend(self._package_versions(page.links, req.name.lower()))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 440, in _package_versions
    for link in self._sort_links(links):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 430, in _sort_links
    for link in links:
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 772, in links
    for anchor in self.parsed.findall(".//a"):
TypeError: findall() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I'm using Windows 7 32bit, Python 2.7

Comment: That exception doesn't match the quoted source line. At all. Did you at any point edit the `pip` source?

Comment: What I'd do at this point: remove the whole `pip` directory from `c:\python27\lib\site-packages\` and re-install. Most likely, the `.pyc` byte cache files are stale, no longer matching the source from `index.py` (and possibly other files). The `parsed` object is just a `html5lib` parse tree, where the `html5lib` library is *included* with the `pip` library source tree.

Comment: I reinstalled it and I got the same result. I didn't edit the pip source

Comment: Did you uninstall first, or only reinstall? The first thing I'd suspect is that there is a read-only `index.pyc` bytecache file in place there with incorrect bytecode.

Comment: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got a bad version of elementtree somehow. In `pip`, `self.parsed` should be an html5lib parse tree object returned by `html5lib.parse` acting on HTML page from the package.  The [readme for html5lib](https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-python) says:

> By default, the document will be an xml.etree element instance. Whenever possible, html5lib chooses the accelerated ElementTree implementation (i.e. xml.etree.cElementTree on Python 2.x).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21539924/findall-takes-exactly-2-arguments-3-given) describes a similar problem in a different context and, hidden in the comments, we see that the OP solved the issue by importing ElementTree differently.  I think you've somehow got some incompatible version(s), maybe of cElementTree, which [html5lib tries to use if it can](https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-python).

I would suggest uninstalling elementtree (if it exists in any of your site-packages directories and you haven't a concrete reason why).  If that doesn't work a complete uninstall / reinstall of `pip` seems the best option.

## Testing for problem (not strictly part of answer)

You can try going to a command prompt and trying `import xml.etree` and `import elementtree`.  If they both work try `help(xml.etree)` and `help(elementtree)` respectively.  Check the build dates given in the DESCRIPTION section.  If you've got a very old (pre-2008) `elementtree` build and don't have a concrete reason why - then uninstall it.