# findall() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, elementtree

here's my code:

```
from elementTree.elementtree.ElementTree import Element, parse, ElementTree

f = open("myxml.xml", 'r')
tree = parse(f)
root = tree.getroot()
f2 = open('out.xml', 'w')

print tree
print root

props = root.findall('property')
print props             

tree.write(f2)
```

Stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xmlpy.py", line 11, in <module>
    props = root.findall('property')
  File "D:\user-testing-areas\DWJ\py\elementTree\elementtree\ElementTree.py", li
ne 390, in findall
    return ElementPath.findall(self, path, namespaces)
TypeError: findall() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I'm following the examples given in the documentation.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that's the code that's giving you the error message?

Comment: Could you post the stack trace?

Comment: Which version of ElementTree are you using? I'm puzzled by the fact that your stack trace seems to point to a location not within a typical Python installation.

Comment: I'm using 1.3.0 I believe: `#
# ElementTree
# $Id: ElementTree.py 3440 2008-07-18 14:45:01Z fredrik $`, Not sure where I got this from though... :-/

Comment: But yip, that appears to be what the problem was, I changed the import to `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET` and it sorted it.